# Need help with Identification

Tags: identification

What is this plant? Where do you plant it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's an Arisaema (Jack in the Pulpit) of some type; probably Asian. It could be Arisaema urashima (syn.  Arisaema thunbergii urashima or Arisaema jacquemontii urashima).

Here's a photo showing similar leaves: http://www.ideasforgardens.net/palustris/Wilmslow/Arisaema%20jacquemontiiurashima.jpg

I own this plant and only get the leaves because it's not happy enough to bloom. Mine is not nearly as tall as the one in your photo (could be cultural, as I've seen it listed at up to 24"/65 cm in height).

If it is an arisaema, then it likes well-drained dappled shade; I believe that this species likes it a little moister than than native US arisaemas, which is why it won't bloom for me.